# Laravel Sort Collection By Dynamic ID array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following...

```
$people = array(5, 2, 9, 6, 11);

$people_collection = People::find($people);
```

But when I dump and die `$people_collection` the collection is ordered by the ID ASC, how can I keep the collection, in the same order as the `$people` array?

Comment: This is because `find` internally calls mysql IN clause which returns the rows in ascending order of the Ids passed. You can manually sort the array or use the method explained by Jannie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Collections has a sortBy function that takes a custom callback:

```
$people_collection = People::find($people)
   ->sortBy(function($person, $key) use($people) {
         return array_search($person->id, $people);
      });
```

See [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortby).